# How to assign a value in one dataframe based on another one where the primary keys can be in a list in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes - DF1 is standard and the SKU is the primary key. DF2 is meant to be more of a map to bucket SKUs together, so the SKUs can be in a list. How do I assign a price value in DF1 based on DF2? The error that I get is "ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series"
DF1

| SKU | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |

DF2

| Price | Included SKUs |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A, C, D |
| 4 | B |

So in this case, SKU A would be assigned a price of 2 and SKU B would be 4.

First I tested

```
print(DF2[DF2['Included SKUs'].str.contains('A')]['Price'])
```

which correctly resulted in the price I wanted. Afterwards I tried to iterate through DF1 and assign prices with the below:

```
for index in range(6):
    sku = DF1.loc[index, 'SKU']
    DF1.loc[index, 'Price'] = DF2[DF2['Included SKUs'].str.contains(str(sku))]['Price']
    print(DF1.loc[index])
```

but I received the error "ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series". How can I assign my prices from DF2 into DF1?

Answer (score 0):

`DF2[DF2['Included SKUs'].str.contains(str(sku))]['Price']` is returning a `Series` which can't be assigned to `DF1.loc[index, 'Price']`. You just need to add a `.values` at the end.

```
for index in range(6):
    sku = DF1.loc[index, 'SKU']
    DF1.loc[index, 'Price'] = DF2[DF2['Included SKUs'].str.contains(str(sku))]['Price'].values
    print(DF1.loc[index])
```